# async method for Receive email in global.asax

Tags: c#, async-await

I have defined a static method for receiving email:

```
public static class Receiver
{
    public static void EmailReceiving()
    {

    }
}
```

in Global.asax, i have defined a timer that receives new emails every 15 minutes.

Global.asax:

```
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    static System.Timers.Timer timer;
    static System.Timers.Timer emailRecieverTimer;

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        emailRecieverTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        emailRecieverTimer.Enabled = true;
        emailRecieverTimer.Interval = 900000;
        emailRecieverTimer.Start();
        emailRecieverTimer.Elapsed += HandleEmailRecieverTimerElapsed;

    }


    public void HandleEmailRecieverTimerElapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Receiver.EmailReceiving();
    }

}
```

Can I define it as an async? Because it is currently running as it runs, the program will be slow to receive emails

Comment: I know you don't want to hear this, but you are using the wrong tool for the job. A web site is meant to receive requests and send repsonses statelessly. You will have challenges trying to put this round peg into the square hole.

Comment: Well if you want to continue your code and exec the unfction, just: Task.Delay(100).ContinueWith(r => Receiver.EmailReceiving()) but indeed seems strange in a website :)

Comment: @ Crowcoder What is the best method and tool to implement this?

Comment: I can't say what would be best for you but common options are console app on scheduled task, windows service. Azure webjob or Function on timer.

Comment: @Crowcoder : Is the Hangfire or Quartz suitable? Which one is better and more perfect?

Comment: I haven't used either one. Certainly that would be an improvement but I personally still wouldn't use a web app for such things.